# Ads aren't showing in android app

Tags: android, adsense, admob, ads, adwhirl

I am using AdWhirl for my ads and they aren't showing in my app when I run it in the emulator. I heard it sometimes takes a while, so i left it for 10 minutes but still nothing. I have disabled AdSense just to see if it would work with just AdMob, but it didn't help.

In my DDMS it shows this:

[image]

It shows the same when AdSense is enabled except it says "AdSense Failure". Has anyone any ideas as to why they aren't showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they do not let your ads load from the emulator. This is to prevent anyone from abusing the system and clicking ads from within the emulator.

Comment: That would make sense. Thank you. I accidentally left the emulator running for two hours and then came back to notice that the ads still weren't showing but the error message was different. It was saying there was no room. I then tested it on my phone again and it worked. I guess it just needed enough requests before AdMob actually started sending ads.